# не работает VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

```
//Если это уведомление о новом сообщении...
case 'like_add':
//...получаем id его автора
$user_id = $data->object->liker_id->from_id;
//затем с помощью users.get получаем данные об авторе
$user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token={$token}&v=5.103"));

//и извлекаем из ответа его имя
$user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;

//С помощью messages.send отправляем ответное сообщение
$request_params = array(
'message' => "вы поставили лайк , {$user_name}!",
'liker_id' => $user_id,
'access_token' => $token,
'v' => '5.103',
'random_id' => '0'
);

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);

file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);

//Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API

echo('ok');

break;
```